# How to word a question where you cite acceptable sources?

Tags: discussion

I'm asking questions where I don't necessarily want to hear what their pastor said, or what some website says, I don't even necessarily want to know what an official plenary session of any denomination said in the past 100 years.

I'm looking for what the popes have said. I'm looking for what was said by major denominational founders, like Luther, Calvin, and Wesley. I'd like to hear what has been said from the "church fathers".  I'm also thinking about famous evangelicals, from tent-revivalists (Finney) to Billy Graham. Really big TV preachers not necessarily to be ruled out. Because of the limitations of this site, I'd be polite and accept Mormon Prophet, even though I don't find it to be within orthodoxy.

**Is there a quick way to say this?**  The way I've worded it in two questions rules out, for example, the Presbyterians and Reformed Church.  While I really don't give a hoot about what motions they passed in the past 50 years, I'm wondering if there's some "famous orthodox" personality that founded those groups.

Comment: Perhaps you could ask for the published works of an individual (rather than a denomination as a whole), perferably with internet links. That would rule out Convention documents and most local pastors.

Comment: I thought the way you phrased the question about Guilt was confusing, seemed like you were calling Luther, Calvin and Wesley (Fathers of the Church).  I don't see how you can expect to get a concrete answer when you seem to want a survey of answers from Pope Francis, Tertullian and Henry VIII.

Comment: Thanks for the good feedback. If I may editorialize here. "Modern theological liberals" are advocating against some traditional interpretations of sin and salvation on the basis of "psychological harm."  I think that's fairly verifiable, historical fact that they do so.  In response, a question of "What do Lutherans teach?" is meaningless here, because the most glaring example of the "abuse" I refer to is a contemporary Lutheran seminary prof.  Can you help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Are there any references from significant church authorities (e.g. Patristic, Papal, or leaders of large-scale movements) ..."